# Books for Business language

Tags: phrase, resource

I have been learning German and I have completed till B2.1. I will be moving to Germany shortly and work there. Though I could discuss in day to day scenarios, I face difficulty in business scenarios and with phrases.

I am looking for a book from which I could learn phrases used in Office and sample polite mails in German.

For ex in English: I have attached the document in this mail 
vs
Please find the document attached with this mail. Please let me know, if you have any questions.

Both the statements above in English mean the same. But, the second one is better suited for Office scenarios. I would like to learn such phrases in German for various scenarios.

Thanks in Advance.

P.S: I have searched for a similar question and couldn't find any. Please let me know, if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the following is what you expected to get here, but...

Your examples would be translated to:

**I have attached the document in this mail** - *Ich habe das Dokument an die E-Mail angehängt.* (not the best phrase) or *Ich habe das Dokument der E-Mail beigefügt.* (a bit better)

**Please find the document attached with this mail** - *Bitte beachten Sie das Dokument im Anhang der E-Mail.* or *Bitte entnehmen Sie das Dokument dem Anhang der E-Mail.*

As often there is not only ONE solution. You already noticed that it is difficult to decide what phrase would fit best. You could also say *Die Informationen können Sie dem Dokument im Anhang entnehmen.*

In most cases it depends on the context. It is also possible to elegantly combine that particular piece of information with an existing sentence, e.g. *[...], wie im Anhang ersichtlich.* and so on.

Since it is a matter of practice your choice to look for business german training is a good one. i opened google and found some resources that might be helpful:

1.

> title: "Geschäftsdeutsch: An Introduction to Business German"
>
> author: Gudrun Clay
>
> publisher: McGraw-Hill
>
> ISBN: 0070113343
>
> GTIN: 09780070113343

2.

> title: "Business Etikette in Deutschland"
>
> authors: Joachim Graff & Gretchen Schaupp
>
> publisher: Co.in Medien
>
> ISBN: 978-3-940574-38-1

3.

> title: "Business-Etikette für Fortgeschrittene: So bewegen Sie sich
>   sicher auf jedem Parkett"
>
> authors: Alexander von Fircks, Agnes Anna Jarosch
>
> publisher: Frankfurter Allgemeine Buch
>
> ISBN: 978-3899811780

4.

> title: "Business-Knigge: Die 100 wichtigsten Benimmregeln"
>
> authors:  Anke Quittschau, Christina Tabernig
>
> publisher: Haufe Lexware
>
> ISBN: 978-3648072424

Also, there are some websites that might be helpful:

> http://www.dw.com/en/learn-german/marktplatz/s-2555
>
> http://www.businessgerman.com/de/
>
> http://www.business-knigge.com/

wishing you success and best results :)

Comment: @Rajkumar all books have a variety of topics like correspondence, negotiations, presentation etc. They are German/from Germany, except the first one. But I think it is not the worst decision to read a book in the language you want to learn anyway ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for the info and the choices as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is my experience that the best website to learn new words is `Memrise`. It is free and there are thousands of coures.

I did not look at deeply. However, there is/are absolutely (a) course(s), which teaches `Business German`.

You can find the site [here](http://www.memrise.com/courses/german/german-2/)

Comment: Thank you for your effort, Ad Infinitum. I have been using Memrise for quite some time. However, I am looking for some definitive material on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: @Rajkumar This link may help you? [link](http://arbeits-abc.de/sprechen-sie-business-deutsche-und-andere-woerter-mit-a-im-alltaeglichen-buerogebrauch/)